# Vue CLI v3 - How does it know what JS files should be chunked in a different file(s)

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I am having hard times wrapping my mind around new CLI and configuration.
In the official documentation, I couldn't really find anything about CSS and how to add it as an entry point and not import it directly into an component or `main.js` file.

I realized that some JS files are being chunked into separate file, from `main.js` and the rest gets compiled where supposed to - into the app.js.

I was wondering, how does it know in the background what should be stored as "vendor" for the JS, but when I try to import some "vendor" SASS files into `main.js` it does not and it merges all within a single `app.css` file.

---

Can anyone tell me, how does one create/modify the `vue.config.js` and tell the bundler that I also want `app.scss` to be an entry point and `vendor.scss` to be another entry point.

I am unsure what are best practices for such purpose, but I always did it this way with my own webpack config...

Partial example below:

```
entry: {
    vendor: [
        './styles/vendor.scss',
        './scripts/vendor.js'
    ],
    app: [
        './styles/app.scss',
        './scripts/app.js'
    ]
}
```

---

**EDIT #1**

I think I got the first one...

"How does it know what should be chunked in "vendor" files?

- Whatever gets imported from node_modules, it is being chunked.

What I did not figure out yet is... What if I am having my personal `assets/styles/vendor` directory where I `@import` those SASS files from NPM and do some modifications of variables or whatever.

Importing this file to `main.js` does not get chunked in this case... So there must be a way to tell bundler that I want everything within that directory or everything within `vendor.scss` file where everything is being imported, to be chunked out.

---

**EDIT #2**

I figured I can use WebPack's magical comments to import the main vendor SCSS file, such as:

`import(/* webpackChunkName: "vendor" */ './assets/styles/vendor.scss')`

I don't have a problem with this, but apparently the bundler does. It generates an empty `vendor.[hash].js` file as well.

---

**EDIT #3**

I did further research and learned that there's a command `vue inspect` which would output the webpack configuration.

So when making tweaks to `vue.config.js`, we can look a the output with this command if there's a bug or something is not working as expected.

Further more, I learned that if we specify `entry` directly in our `vue.config.js` file, that we will get an error that `entry` cannot be specified within our configuration file.

The following is forbidden to do so, but it's what I actually want to achieve...

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [
      './src/main.js',
      './src/assets/styles/app.scss'
    ],
    vendor: [
      './src/assets/styles/vendor.scss'
    ]
  }
}
```

The actual proper way to do this will be an answer to my own question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this is by using WebPack's Chain API.

However, if I did everything correctly, I still see a problem of generated `vendor.[hash].js` file with some WebPack module boilerplate. This JS file is also being injected to the `index.html` template.

Which leads to the same outcome as the attempt of my **EDIT #2**, except that we're no longer importing our Sass files within `main.js`

To modify entry points for my purpose of this question, we can do it the following way:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .entry('app')
        .add('./src/assets/styles/app.scss')
        .end()
      .entry('vendor')
        .add('./src/assets/styles/vendor.scss')
      .end()
  }
}
```

**Note**

We're not specifying the `app` entry JS file, which would be `main.js` by default, because we're not overriding the current entry point. Instead, we're extending it, so everything works as expected.

---

**UPDATE**

Until WebPack resolves this in future major releases, I found a great package - [fqborges/webpack-fix-style-only-entries](https://github.com/fqborges/webpack-fix-style-only-entries). It solves this issue that I was having and I'd suggest you to use it.

Final configuration would look like this:

```
const FixStyleOnlyEntries = require('webpack-fix-style-only-entries')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .entry('app')
        .add('./src/assets/styles/app.scss')
        .end()
      .entry('vendor')
        .add('./src/assets/styles/vendor.scss')
      .end()
  },

  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new FixStyleOnlyEntries()
    ]
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

After further investigation and use of such configuration for projects, I realized that I had to use `!important` in styles where I had a need to override anything `vendor` related.

This is simply because WebPack will inject `app`, before `vendor` (both JS and CSS) and it will cause such issue.

Even if we modify the configuration from above and move `app` entry, below the `vendor` entry, it will still fail. Reason being, because we're modifying the entry point which already exists by default within `vue-cli` config. We're adding more entries to the `app` and we're adding new `vendor` entry.

To fix this issue of ordering, we must delete the `app` entirely and then create it ourselves.

```
const FixStyleOnlyEntries = require('webpack-fix-style-only-entries')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.entryPoints.delete('app')

    config
      .entry('vendor')
        .add('./src/assets/styles/vendor.scss')
      .end()
      .entry('app')
        .add('./src/main.js')
        .add('./src/assets/styles/app.scss')
      .end()
  },

  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new FixStyleOnlyEntries()
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Opened the issue on their GH repository. 
Will keep this question updated and hope it's a CLI bug...

Comment: It's a WebPack issue, so nothing to worry about. Answer is within the link above... Waiting for WebPack to make that possible, but until then, I must find a workaround.